# Is eating eggs bad for me?

Tags: nutrition

I read yesterday that a single egg contains 70% of my daily cholesterol. I will frequently cook myself an omlette for lunch with 2-3 eggs. Is this unhealthy if I do it more than once a week?

Comment: +1! Folklore in my country says that you shouldn't eat more than 3 eggs a week, but I never took the time to research the theory behind that.

Comment: strange, here it says no more than 3 a day :)

Comment: Cholesterol in food is not problem as to my understanding body just produces less cholesterol to take account the cholesterol in food.

Comment: Have you a reference to back that up, @Illotus?

Comment: More than 3 per minute is said to be of non benefit, in the long run.

Comment: I think we can agree that the number 3 is key here.

Comment: @Oddthinking "The response of cholesterogenesis to different amounts of dietary cholesterol was related to the rate of synthesis under depressed conditions of the low-cholesterol diet. These findings indicate modest downregulation of synthesis in response to dietary cholesterol in humans, independent of plasma cholesterol levels." http://atvb.ahajournals.org/content/16/10/1222.short

Comment: @Illotus, thanks for the link! Maybe I'm nerdy, but that's a pretty cool little experiment! It certainly shows the body produces less cholesterol if you eat more of it. It doesn't quite prove that dietary cholesterol is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/7882850.stm) quotes [Professor Bruce Griffin](http://www.surrey.ac.uk/fhms/people/atoz/griffin_bruce/index.htm) as saying:

> "The ingrained misconception linking egg consumption to high blood cholesterol and heart disease must be corrected.
>   The amount of saturated fat in our diet exerts an effect on blood cholesterol that is several times greater than the relatively small amounts of dietary cholesterol.
>   The UK public do not need to be limiting the number of eggs they eat - indeed they can be encouraged to include them in a healthy diet as they are one of nature's most nutritionally dense foods."

The [British Heart Foundation](https://www.bhf.org.uk/default.aspx?page=12920) make the point that the eggs are fine, but the other things you add during cooking, such as butter fat etc are why eating a lot of eggs would be bad.

Comment: I substantially edited this answer to bring it in line with the current expected standards of Skeptics.SE (although quoting a peer-reviewed paper would make it better still.) I also deleted a lot of banter in the comments which is no longer relevant.

Comment: And whether butter fat is harmful is also a highly contested claim.

Comment: OK, what about the doctors that keep on saying it's unhealthy to eat eggs everyday?